# ReactJs is it possible to update title as dynamic in index.html

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I aware that when we sending some of the url through whatsapp there will include the title, icon and description. I have a website that build using reactjs which host `www.url.com`. I try to update the title and description dynamic as i need to send the url like `url/product1` to others. 

As i had tried like using react-helmet but it cause the url i send it just remain link without the icon, title and description.

Is there any ways i can pass the value to index.html to update the icon, title and description of it?

Comment: `
const withPageTitle = (title) => (Component) => (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
    return () => {
      document.title = 'default_app_name';
    };
  }, []);
  return <Component {...props} />;
}
`

and then e.g you can wrap Users with the HOC

withPageTitle('Users')(Users) - this will change the page title to users when you navigate to it.

Not sure this is what your looking for so I added it as a comment

Comment: I think you're going to implement OpenGraph. Unfortunately, you cannot reach it with plain React itself. You'd better use Next JS if you want opengraph to work individually on every page.